# Is it possible to add a sound to a notification reply upon successful delivery, like iMessage?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios9

In iMessage for iOS, when you pull down from a notification to reply, upon sending successfully it plays a sound. Is this available for third party developers?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can only use native sounds using soundName inside of the UILocalNotification class. This might help: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html

Comment: @user2277872 It's not a local notification so I'm fine with using whatever sound, the issue is having it play on successful delivery of the response send, not the initial reception.

Answer (score -1):

Using the

> UILocalNotification

**property**

> soundName

. You can set the sound to notification.

**localNotif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;**

**Sample:**

```
 - (void)scheduleNotificationWithItem:(ToDoItem *)item interval:(int)minutesBefore  {
     NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar];
     NSDateComponents *dateComps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
     [dateComps setDay:item.day];
     [dateComps setMonth:item.month];
     [dateComps setYear:item.year];
     [dateComps setHour:item.hour];
     [dateComps setMinute:item.minute];
     NSDate *itemDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:dateComps];

     UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
     if (localNotif == nil)
         return;
     localNotif.fireDate = [itemDate dateByAddingTimeIntervalInterval:-(minutesBefore*60)];
     localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

     localNotif.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"%@ in %i minutes.", nil),
          item.eventName, minutesBefore];
     localNotif.alertAction = NSLocalizedString(@"View Details", nil);
     localNotif.alertTitle = NSLocalizedString(@"Item Due", nil);

     localNotif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
     localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;

     NSDictionary *infoDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:item.eventName forKey:ToDoItemKey];
     localNotif.userInfo = infoDict;

     [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif]; 

}
```

If you want to set the **custom sound**. make sure that it support **caf** format and the audio **duration is less than 30 seconds**.

**localNotif.soundName = @"xyz.caf"**

Comment: That's not what the question asks, it's if you can play a sound upon successful delivery, not on reception.